# Finding direct children in a geb module

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, geb

I'm trying to write `geb` modules to handle rows and columns of div tags as follows:

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     ...
       <div class="row">...</div>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And have the `geb` modules:

```groovy
class GridRowModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        columns { $("div", 'class': startsWith('col-')) }
    }
}

class GridLayoutModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        rows { index -> moduleList GridRowModule, $(".row"), index }
    }
}

class ContainerModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        container { module GridLayoutModule, $(".container") }
    }

}
```

But the nagivator for rows `$(".row")` finds all rows recursively. How can I limit the search to one level only?

Using the css selector, I'd like to write `$(".container > .row")` but then I break the general module approach. Can I do this from within the module somehow? A way to access the parent css selector?

Or is there any other way in `geb` to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children(".row")` instead of `$(".row")` solved my problem! So the solution would be:

```groovy
class GridRowModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        columns { children("div", 'class': startsWith('col-')) }
    }
}

class GridLayoutModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        rows { index -> moduleList GridRowModule, children(".row"), index }
    }
}

class ContainerModule extends Module {
    static content = {
        container { module GridLayoutModule, $(".container") }
    }

}
```